# TextField inside of Row causes layout exception: Unable to calculate size

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-text, flutter-row

I’m getting a rendering exception that I don’t understand how to fix. I’m attempting to create a column that has 3 rows.

Row [Image]

Row [TextField ]

Row [Buttons]

Here is my code to build the container:

```
Container buildEnterAppContainer(BuildContext context) {
    var container = new Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: new Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          buildImageRow(context),
          buildAppEntryRow(context),
          buildButtonRow(context)
        ],
      ),
    );
    return container;
  }
```

and my buildAppEntryRow code for the text container

```
Widget buildAppEntryRow(BuildContext context) {
    return new Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        new TextField(
          decoration: const InputDecoration(helperText: "Enter App ID"),
          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.body1,
        )
      ],
    );
  }
```

When I run I get the following exception:

```
I/flutter ( 7674): BoxConstraints forces an infinite width.
I/flutter ( 7674): These invalid constraints were provided to RenderStack's layout() function by the following
I/flutter ( 7674): function, which probably computed the invalid constraints in question:
I/flutter ( 7674):   RenderConstrainedBox.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:256:13)
I/flutter ( 7674): The offending constraints were:
I/flutter ( 7674):   BoxConstraints(w=Infinity, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
```

If i change buildAppEntryRow to just a TextField instead like this

```
 Widget buildAppEntryRow2(BuildContext context) {
    return new TextField(
      decoration: const InputDecoration(helperText: "Enter App ID"),
      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.body1,
    );
  }
```

I no longer get the exception. What am I missing with the Row implementation that is causing it to not be able to calculate the size of that row?

Answer (score 631, accepted):

(I assume you're using a `Row` because you want to put other widgets beside the `TextField` in the future.)

The `Row` widget wants to determine the intrinsic size of its non-flexible children so it knows how much space that it has left for the flexible ones. However, `TextField` doesn't have an intrinsic width; it only knows how to size itself to the full width of its parent container. Try wrapping it in a `Flexible` or `Expanded` to tell the `Row` that you're expecting the `TextField` to take up the remaining space:

```
      new Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          new Flexible(
            child: new TextField(
              decoration: const InputDecoration(helperText: "Enter App ID"),
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.body1,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

Comment: Shouldn't this be on flutter doc somewhere?

Comment: @stt106 it is --> https://flutter.io/docs/development/ui/layout/box-constraints But I agree, it isn't easy to find. Nor do they make the solution as obvious as Collin Jackson did above.

Comment: Using this method breaks `mainAxisAlignment` for the Row widget. With two text widgets there's no problem but with a text widget and a Textfield widget contained in `Flexible` it gets aligned to the left with no spacing.

Comment: May I ask you to take a look at a Flutter related question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60565658/fluter-image-picker-package-show-images-one-after-another-with-delete-action ?

Comment: For some reason this small change required a Flutter Hot Restart (not just Hot Reload) in order to make the layout exception go away in my case.

Answer (score 114):

You get this error because `TextField` expands in horizontal direction and so does the `Row`, so we need to constrain the width of the `TextField`, there are many ways of doing it.

1. Use `Expanded`

   ```
    Row(
     children: <Widget>[
       Expanded(child: TextField()),
       OtherWidget(),
     ],
   )
   ```
2. Use `Flexible`

   ```
   Row(
     children: <Widget>[
       Flexible(child: TextField()),
       OtherWidget(),
     ],
   )
   ```
3. Wrap it in `Container` or `SizedBox` and provide `width`

   ```
   Row(
     children: <Widget>[
       SizedBox(width: 100, child: TextField()),
       OtherWidget(),
     ],
   )
   ```

Comment: This recommendation is so useful. When you have multiple `TextField` in one row.

Comment: In Row Flexible is perfect. Expanded has fixed height and i crash validation text

Comment: SizedBox did what I needed in my app.

Comment: `Expanded` and `Flexible` options did not work when parent widget width wasnt hardcoded

Comment: You must add Expanded or Flexible widget as a parent of all widgets that contains the TextField

Answer (score 15):

you should use Flexible to use a Textfield inside a row.

```
new Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                new Text("hi there"),
                new Container(
                  child:new Flexible(
                        child: new TextField( ),
                            ),//flexible
                ),//container


              ],//widget
            ),//row
```

Comment: I think you don't need the `Container`, you can use the `Flexible` directly.

Answer (score 9):

The solution is to wrap your `Text()` inside one of the following widgets: 
Either [`Expanded`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html) or [`Flexible`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Flexible-class.html). So, your code using Expanded will be like:

```
Expanded(
           child: TextField(
             decoration: InputDecoration(
               hintText: "Demo Text",
               hintStyle: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w300, color: Colors.red)
              ),
           ),
        ),
```

Answer (score 7):

As @Asif Shiraz mentioned I had same issue and solved this by Wrapping Column in a Flexible, here like this,,

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        theme: new ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
        home: new Scaffold(
          body: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Flexible(
                  child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    child: TextField(),
                  )
                  //container
                ],
              ))
            ],
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

The `InputDecoration` of a `TextField` can cause an infinite width problem when placed inside a `Row`. Flutter explains this in the `InputDecoration` [constraints property](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InputDecoration/constraints.html) documentation:

> Typically the decorator will fill the horizontal space it is given. ... If null, then the ambient `ThemeData.inputDecorationTheme`'s `InputDecorationTheme.constraints` will be used. **If that is null then the decorator will fill the available width** with a default height based on text size.

So, the good news is that the width of a `TextField` can be constrained without the use of surrounding widgets like `Expanded`. Simply provide an instance of `BoxConstraints` to the `constraints` parameter of the `InputDecoration` that the `TextField` widget uses:

```
const TextField(
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    constraints: BoxConstraints.tightFor(
          width: 200,
    ),
  ),
)
```

As mentioned in the Flutter documentation above, a set of constraints can be applied to several widgets at once by using a `Theme` with a `ThemeData` that specifies an `InputDecorationTheme` with the  desired constraints for descendent widgets of the `Theme` to inherit from and use.

Answer (score 3):

```
Row(
      children: [
        Expanded(
          flex: 1,
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 5.0,right: 5.0),
            child: TextFormField(
              controller: commentController,
              validator: (String value){
                if(value.isEmpty){
                  // ignore: missing_return
                  return 'Comment cannot be blank.';
                }
              },
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: "Comment",
                  labelStyle: TextStyle(
                      fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      color: Colors.grey),
                  focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.green))),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

If you want, you can use **Table** widget to avoid this kind of issue with **TextField**

Answer (score 0):

> the best solution is with absouluts space values

```
        Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.3, 
              child: _telephonePrefixInput()
            ),
            SizedBox(width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.02),
            Expanded(child: _telephoneInput()),
          ],
        ),
```

Answer (score -1):

A simple solution is to wrap your `Text()` inside a `Container()`.
So, your code will be like:

```
Container(
      child: TextField()
)
```

Here you also get the width and height attribute of a container to adjust the look and feel of your text field. No need to use `Flexible` if you are wrapping your text field inside of a Container.

Comment: doesn't solve the question without adding `width: n`

Answer (score -1):

If you want your TextField to size itself horizontally based on its content then you can wrap it with IntrinsicWidth widget.

```
Row(
 children: [
    Text("From"),
    SizedBox(width: 10,),
    IntrinsicWidth(child: TextField(
        textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.center,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
        hintText:  "Start Date Start Date Start Date",
        hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colour.pBlue, fontSize: 14),
        border: InputBorder.none,
      ),
    ),),
            SizedBox(width: 10,),
            Text("To"),
            SizedBox(width: 10,),
            IntrinsicWidth(child:  IntrinsicWidth(child: TextField(
     textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.center,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        hintText:  "End Date",
        hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colour.pBlue, fontSize: 14),
        border: InputBorder.none,
      ),
    ),)),
          ],
        )
```

But before using it in your code make sure to know what Flutter says about this widget.

> Creates a widget that sizes its child to the child's intrinsic width.
> This class is relatively expensive. Avoid using it where possible.