# BoxConstraints forces an infinite width

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, width

I am getting an error when I add a row in a column. I am getting the following error:

```
I/flutter ( 6449): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY RENDERING LIBRARY ╞═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter ( 6449): The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
I/flutter ( 6449): BoxConstraints forces an infinite width.
I/flutter ( 6449): These invalid constraints were provided to RenderAnimatedOpacity's layout() function
```

Also for reference here is my code:

```
return new Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: whiteColor,
      body: new Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          imgHeader,
          lblSignUp,
          txtEmail,
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              txtFirstName,
              txtLastName
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

Answer (score 99, accepted):

If you are using `TextField` Inside a `Row` then you need to use `Flexible` or `Expanded`.

More details are given here in this answer.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/45990477/4652688

Comment: Nice! `Flexible` produces exactly the sort of behavior that I was looking for. Thank you! =^,^=

Answer (score 65):

**Reason for the error:**

`TextField` expands in horizontal direction and so does the `Row`, so we need to constrain the width of the `TextField`, there are many ways of doing it.

1. Use `Expanded`

   ```
    Row(
     children: <Widget>[
       Expanded(child: TextField()),
       // more widgets
     ],
   )
   ```
2. Use `Flexible`

   ```
   Row(
     children: <Widget>[
       Flexible(child: TextField()),
       // more widgets
     ],
   )
   ```
3. Wrap it in `Container` or `SizedBox` and provide `width`

   ```
   Row(
     children: <Widget>[
       SizedBox(width: 100, child: TextField()),
       // more widgets
     ],
   )
   ```

Comment: I had a ListView that was throwing this exception and wrapping it in a SizedBox and setting the width worked for me! Thanks.

Comment: Flexible() widget saved my day!. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Giving the reason helped me in a different (ListView) problem.

Answer (score 4):

I got this error when using a `Positioned` widget along the lines of:

```dart
Positioned(
  left: _left,
  child: MyWidget(...)
)
```

And solved by adding the `bottom` and `top` arguments, e.g.:

```dart
Positioned(
  left: _left,
  bottom: 0,
  top: 0,
  child: MyWidget(...)
)
```