# Flutter - BoxConstraints forces an infinite width

Tags: flutter

How put orange container full width?

[image]

I'm try with double.infinity but get error BoxConstraints forces an infinite width.

```
    Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
      height: 205,
      color: Colors.grey,
      //margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20),
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          Positioned(
            left: 0,
            bottom: 0,
            child: Container(
              height: 185,
              width: 350,  //double.infinity --not working
              color: Colors.deepOrange,
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(
            right:0,
            top:0,
            child: Image.asset('assets/images/book-1.png',width: 150,),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    )
```

Comment: Is this container inside a `listview` or any other scrollable widget?

Comment: @AmirHosseinRahmanzadeh  Scaffold >  SingleChildScrollView  >  Column and then Contaiiner,  before this Container in Column I have other Container and SizedBox

Comment: You can not have widgets with the height of infinity inside any vertical scrollable widget such as `SingleChildScrollView`

Comment: Is this `Container` code snippet inside the same file or separated one? can you include parent's details ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [BoxConstraints forces an infinite width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52442724/boxconstraints-forces-an-infinite-width)

Answer (score -1):

You can use `MediaQuery.of(context).size.width` for full screen width of Container widget.