# wrap long text inside parent widget

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a long text in which i want it to be warped into parent width ..

what am getting right now is:

[image]

and my code is:

```
     new Padding(
              padding: new EdgeInsets.only(right: 15.0, left: 15.0),
              child: new Container(
                width: double.infinity,
                color: Color(0xFFF5F5F5),
                child: new Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    new Padding(
                      padding: new EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                        child: Text(
                          'في ظل الازدهار والنمو المستمر للاقتصاد الوطني والتوسع الكبير في حجم الأعمال تزداد الحاجة يوماً بعد يوم إلى توظيف المزيد من الموظفين الأكفاء ، وتواجه الكثير من المنشآت تحديات كبيرة في ايجاد هؤلاء الموظفين \n\n وحيث تعتبر معارض التوظيف أحدى أهم الوسائل لأصحاب العمل في الحصول على احتياجاتهم من الكفاءات والكوادر الوطنية المتخصصة ،فقد أتت مبادرة غرفة الشرقية بإقامة معرض توظيف موسع بمسمى (معرض وظائف) يمكن من خلاله لأصحاب العمل ومسئولي الموارد البشرية ومسئولي التوظيف الالتقاء والتواصل المباشر مع عدد كبير جداً من خريجي كافة المراحل التعليمية وعرض الشواغر المتوفرة لديها واستقطاب أفضل المتقدمين للعمل لديها \n\n كما سيكون المعرض فرصة مناسبة لطالبي العمل من الخريجين الجدد وأصحاب الخبرات لتسويق أنفسهم على المنشآت المشاركة والتنافس على الوظائف المعروضة كمرشحين محتملين للعمل لدى هذه المنشآت مما سيعزز فرصهم في الحصول على الوظائف التي تتوافق مع طموحهم وميولهم ومهارتهم وقدراتهم بالإضافة إلى ذلك سيكون المعرض فرصة مناسبة للالتقاء مع المشاركين من المختصين في مجال الموارد البشرية ومجال التدريب والتأهيل لعرض مايقدمونه من خدمات للمنشآت المشاركة وللزوار ولطالبي العمل',
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 14.0),
                          textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
```

i want the text to be multi-lined and wrapped inside the gray container...

how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a `Flexible` (or Expanded) should do what you want:

```
new Row(
  children: <Widget>[
    new Flexible(child:
      new Padding(
        padding: new EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
          child: Text(
            'في ظل الازدهار والنمو المستمر للاقتصاد الوطني والتوسع الكبير في حجم الأعمال تزداد الحاجة يوماً بعد يوم إلى توظيف المزيد من الموظفين الأكفاء ، وتواجه الكثير من المنشآت تحديات كبيرة في ايجاد هؤلاء الموظفين \n\n وحيث تعتبر معارض التوظيف أحدى أهم الوسائل لأصحاب العمل في الحصول على احتياجاتهم من الكفاءات والكوادر الوطنية المتخصصة ،فقد أتت مبادرة غرفة الشرقية بإقامة معرض توظيف موسع بمسمى (معرض وظائف) يمكن من خلاله لأصحاب العمل ومسئولي الموارد البشرية ومسئولي التوظيف الالتقاء والتواصل المباشر مع عدد كبير جداً من خريجي كافة المراحل التعليمية وعرض الشواغر المتوفرة لديها واستقطاب أفضل المتقدمين للعمل لديها \n\n كما سيكون المعرض فرصة مناسبة لطالبي العمل من الخريجين الجدد وأصحاب الخبرات لتسويق أنفسهم على المنشآت المشاركة والتنافس على الوظائف المعروضة كمرشحين محتملين للعمل لدى هذه المنشآت مما سيعزز فرصهم في الحصول على الوظائف التي تتوافق مع طموحهم وميولهم ومهارتهم وقدراتهم بالإضافة إلى ذلك سيكون المعرض فرصة مناسبة للالتقاء مع المشاركين من المختصين في مجال الموارد البشرية ومجال التدريب والتأهيل لعرض مايقدمونه من خدمات للمنشآت المشاركة وللزوار ولطالبي العمل',
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 14.0),
            textAlign: TextAlign.right,
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ],
),
```

See also [TextField inside of Row causes layout exception: Unable to calculate size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45986093/textfield-inside-of-row-causes-layout-exception-unable-to-calculate-size)