# RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded have tried for flexible and expanded does not work

Tags: flutter, textfield

I have below codes. I have google around

e.g. [TextField inside of Row causes layout exception: Unable to calculate size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45986093/textfield-inside-of-row-causes-layout-exception-unable-to-calculate-size). The issue is in my case is this

```
TextFormField( onChanged: (value) => contactNo = value,
```

I have tried expanded, I have tried flexible etc all does not work and gives me error. What else should I fix in this case ? I have tried adding this child: SingleChildScrollView( and even this mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
Yet the same errors.

```
Widget _createForm(BuildContext context) {    
      return Scaffold(      
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
      resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
      backgroundColor: pagebackgroundColor,
      appBar: appBar(),
      drawer: Theme(
          data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(canvasColor: Colors.white),
          child: new ReusableWidgets().getDrawer('Sum',context)
      ),
        body: SafeArea(
                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 20.0,
                    ),

                    Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        RoundedCardDataNoColor(

                          child: Row( 
                            //mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: <Widget>[              
                              Column(
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                children: <Widget>[
                                        Row(
                                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                          children: <Widget>[                            
                                            SizedBox(width: 5,),
                                            Text(
                                              "Total",
                                              style: plateStyle,
                                            ),

                                          ],
                                        ),

                                        SizedBox(height: 5,),

                                        Expanded(
                                          child:
                                          Row(
                                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                            children: <Widget>[
                                                  TextFormField(
                                                  onChanged: (value) => contactNo = value,
                                                  keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
                                                  validator: validateMobile,
                                                  maxLength: 10,
                                                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                                                    labelText: 'Contact No.',
                                                    //errorText: "Enter First Name",
                                                  ),
                                                ), 

                                            ],
                                           ),
                                        )
                                      ],
                              ),
                            ]
                          )
                        ),
                      ]
                    ),
```

Here is the full errors.

> RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming width constraints are unbounded.
>   The relevant error-causing widget was
>           Row 
>   RenderBox was not laid out: RenderFlex#03f25 relayoutBoundary=up16 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
>       'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
>       Failed assertion: line 1687 pos 12: 'hasSize'
>       The relevant error-causing widget was
>           Column 
>       RenderBox was not laid out: RenderFlex#adff1 relayoutBoundary=up15 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
>       'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
>       Failed assertion: line 1687 pos 12: 'hasSize'
>       The relevant error-causing widget was
>           Row

From here onwards it pointing to my round_card_data_nocolor widget which I have created

> RenderBox was not laid out: RenderFlex#6e81b relayoutBoundary=up14 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
>       'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
>       Failed assertion: line 1687 pos 12: 'hasSize'
>       The relevant error-causing widget was
>           Container 
>       RenderBox was not laid out: RenderPadding#88382 relayoutBoundary=up13 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
>       'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
>       Failed assertion: line 1687 pos 12: 'hasSize'
>       The relevant error-causing widget was
>           Container 
>       RenderBox was not laid out: RenderDecoratedBox#f5086 relayoutBoundary=up12 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
>       'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
>       Failed assertion: line 1687 pos 12: 'hasSize'
>       The relevant error-causing widget was
>           Row 
>       RenderBox was not laid out: RenderFlex#72dfe relayoutBoundary=up11 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
>       'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
>       Failed assertion: line 1687 pos 12: 'hasSize'
>       The relevant error-causing widget was
>           Card 
>       RenderBox was not laid out: RenderSemanticsAnnotations#16c58 relayoutBoundary=up5 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
>       'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
>       Failed assertion: line 1687 pos 12: 'hasSize'
>       The relevant error-causing widget was
>           Padding

Here is the full codes for the widget RoundedCardDataNoColor:

```java
    class RoundedCardDataNoColor extends StatelessWidget {
      // ---- props -----
      final Widget child;


      // --- constant view settings ----
      static const double radius = 10.0;
      static const double elevation = 5.0;
      static const innerPadding = const EdgeInsets.all(8.0);
      static const innerPaddingColor = const EdgeInsets.all(0.0);
      static const outerPadding = const EdgeInsets.all(0.0);
      static const margin = const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 5, 0, 5);

      const RoundedCardDataNoColor({
        Key key,
        this.child,
      }) : super(key: key);

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Padding(
          padding: outerPadding,
          child: Card(
            margin: margin,
            elevation: elevation,
            clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
            shape: roundShape,
            child: Row(children: <Widget>[
              new Container(
              padding: innerPadding,
              decoration: roundDecor,
              child: child ,
              ),
            ],)


          ),
        );
      }


      static const roundShape = const RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
          topLeft: Radius.circular(radius),
          bottomLeft: Radius.circular(radius),
        ),
      );

      static const roundDecor = const BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.white,
        borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
            topLeft: const Radius.circular(radius),
            bottomLeft: const Radius.circular(radius)),
      );
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A ScrollView doesn't define a height constraint, only a width constraint. Inside your second `Column` it looks like you're defining an `Expanded`, which means that widget will try and expand vertically "unbounded" by a height constraint. You can try removing the `Expanded` and see if that does it or adding a fixed height to `RoundedCardDataNoColor`

Comment: I tried removing the expanded no it does not help. I  don't know what height to set for my RoundedCardDataNoColor. I tried removing everything and put a container with fix height looks OK but its not able to take full space. What dynamic solution can I work on?

Comment: Another issue I've previously had is putting `TextField`s inside Rows without adding an `Expanded` (or any Flex widget) as their parent. (That or try removing the Row above the TextFormField altogether.) I don't think they have an implicit max width constraint and have a similar issue to Expandeds inside Scrollviews

Comment: I dont quite get you on this you mean just leave with expanded but no row is it ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I explained myself too well. Take a look at this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45990477/8213910). Essentially just wrap your TextFormField in an Expanded if you want to keep on using it in a row

Comment: @Nolene no I tried that answer before posting here in my case it does not work. I get this error The method '>' was called on null. ..

Comment: I'm really embarrassed to have posted the same stack overflow answer! If you could, please add the full error stack trace to your question

Comment: @Nolene no issue dont be embarrassed. I have updated my question with all the details and the full error. I have given the codes for my RoundedCardDataNoColor which is a widget I customised could be that also is an issue thats what I am seeing the errors too?

Answer (score 4):

Wrap your Column inside an Expanded or SizedBox (with some height) like below:

```js
Expanded(
  child: Column(...)
)
```

Or

```js
SizedBox(
  height: 150, // give height
  child: Column(...),
)
```